# How can I insert in script?

Tags: python

I want to know how can I insert the `FİGLET` extension into my script.
How a user can view the output of my code without having the figlet..

```
import pyfiglet
print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("hello"))
```

```
>>> import pyfiglet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that pyfiglet is not installed, you can install it by using pip in the console:

```
pip install pyfiglet
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to be able to use the `pyfiglet.figlet_format` if and only if `pyfiglet` is available to import, and just print the plain text otherwise, then this may do the trick:

```py
try:
    from pyfiglet import figlet_format
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    def figlet_format(text):
        '''Shim for missing pyfiglet module'''
        return text

print(figlet_format("hello"))
```